# Passing ListViewItems aross pages

Tags: c#, listview, data-binding, windows-phone-8.1

I am using `Windows Phone 8.1` and I am wondering how do I pass Binded values across pages? I have already binded the data to my `ListView` as shown below. And also, how do I retrieve the values from the page.

E.g. when I click the "Name" I would go to the EnterAmount and pass all the 5 Binded Data to it.

Is my method of doing correct? Or is there a simpler way of accomplishing this.
And also, may know how do I concatinate first_name and last_name into a single row?

I want it displayed like

---

First Name + Last Name

Item Name

---

Much appreciated

**SelectItem.xaml**

```
<ListView Name="ItemList"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" 
    Margin="40,300,0,0"
    Height="200" 
    Width="320" 
    IsItemClickEnabled="True"
    ItemClick="ItemList_ItemClick">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
                <TextBlock Width="200" 
                           FontSize="20" 
                           Foreground="#FFFF7B2C"
                           Text="{Binding item_id}" 
                           Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                <TextBlock Width="200" 
                           FontSize="20" 
                           Foreground="#FFFF7B2C"
                           Text="{Binding first_name}" />
                <TextBlock Width="200" 
                           FontSize="20" 
                           Foreground="#FFFF7B2C"
                           Text="{Binding last_name}" />
                <TextBlock Width="200" 
                           FontSize="20" 
                           Foreground="#FFFF7B2C"
                           Text="{Binding item_name}" />
                <TextBlock Width="200" 
                           FontSize="20" 
                           Foreground="#FFFF7B2C"
                           Text="{Binding progress}" 
                           Visibility="Collapsed"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

**SelectItem.xaml.cs**

```
private void ItemList_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    //this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(EnterAmount), e.ClickedItem);
}
```

Comment: Don't pass UI elements between pages, pass data or reference to data. Also passing ListViewItem will fail as only basic types should be passed via Navigate method - the SuspensionManager won't be able to serialize your passed non-basic type.

Comment: @Romasz May I have an example on how do I do that? I am kind of new to this

Comment: There are couple of ways to do it. One example may be to pass Item's index of ItemsSource collection, and if the collection is accessible from other page then you can access item by Collection[index]. Obtaining the index can look for example like this: `int index = (sender as ListView).Items.IndexOf(e.ClickedItem);`